# How to use case with withSum in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `posts` table and a `comments` table. A post can have many comments. `comments` has a field called `stars`. I want to get all posts alongside the rank. Rank is basically the stars in comments where if the `stars` is 3 then the rank would be 5.

I tried the following,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Post::withSum(
        'comments as rank'
    , 'CASE WHEN stars > 3 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END')->get();
});
```

I get the error,

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.CASE WHEN stars > 3 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT
  `posts`.*,
  (
    SELECT
      sum(
        `comments`.`CASE WHEN stars > 3 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END`
      )
    FROM
      `comments`
    WHERE
      `posts`.`id` = `comments`.`post_id`
  ) AS `rank`
FROM
  `posts`
```

Looks like laravel is messig up the syntax `comments`.`CASE WHEN stars > 3 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END`. How do I fix it?

Repository: https://github.com/axelthat/laravel9-issue

Comment: If it's not a straight `column` or `column AS name`, then you need to use a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: I get same error. Here is the repository: https://github.com/axelthat/laravel9-issue.

Comment: Your query is wrong. You are mix up SQL query and laravel eloquent orm. The way use are using `withSum` is completely wrong.  You mentioned If stars is 3 the rank is 5. If the sum of all comments stars of related post be 3 , the rank of post is 5?? Please clear it to may I can post correct query.

Comment: Missed the `withSum`, which you really can't use with a CASE here, I think. You're going to have to use regular query builder queries with Raw statements on a relationship query.